# android connection to wamp server

Tags: php, android

favorite
I am trying to connect to localhost WAMP Apache server from my android Emulator. But connections is getting refused. All the details provided below. Please help me out.

```
package com.example.omen.test;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
     {
String json_string;
         final  String TAG= "ali";
         RequestQueue rq ;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    String url="https://10.0.2.2/oncfapp/oncf1.php";
   //String url="https://google.com";
 StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
 @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
Log.d(TAG, response);
        }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"erreur",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

and this the what s appears in the monitor:

```
08-01 18:20:59.915 2882-2882/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-01 18:20:59.990 2882-2882/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-01 18:21:00.558 2882-2933/com.example.omen.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-01 18:21:00.661 2882-2933/com.example.omen.test W/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::Mapper: getService: found null hwbinder interface
```

but when i set an other adress like google it works , please help

Comment: Is your webserver accessible from outside your local network (ou outside your server itself)?

Comment: no it's not but i think that's is not important

Comment: Your webserver needs to be accessible on your local network not on your machine only.

Comment: how can i make it accessible in my local network ??

Comment: The server needs to be accessible for it to work. If your server isn't accessible, you can't connect to it. Don't ask me how it can be made accessible, I have never used wamp

Comment: Click on the Wamp icon and click on the "online" Burton. Then try to access your URL from another computer or from your Android Web browser.

Comment: IT dosen t work , i modified my httpd.config in my wamp and set allow from all but when i type my  pc ip address  in the phone browser it dont give me the wamps page , I don t know where is the problem